# What indexes would help speed this query up?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have the following query that's currently taking around 450ms to run:

```
SELECT stripe_balance_transactions.created, fee, stripe_charges.plan 
FROM stripe_balance_transactions
JOIN stripe_charges ON stripe_balance_transactions.source = stripe_charges.stripe_id 
WHERE 
   stripe_balance_transactions.account_id = 93 
   AND (stripe_balance_transactions.type = 'charge' AND stripe_charges.refunded = false) 
   AND (stripe_charges.invoice IS NOT NULL) 
   AND (stripe_balance_transactions.created BETWEEN '2013-01-20 00:00:00.000000' AND '2014-02-19 23:59:59.999999') 
ORDER BY stripe_balance_transactions.created;
```

Are there any additional indexes I could be using here to try and speed that query up?

Here's the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
 Sort  (cost=30742.84..30748.08 rows=2096 width=25) (actual time=456.942..457.082 rows=1579 loops=1)
   Sort Key: stripe_balance_transactions.created
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 138kB
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=24408.50..30627.21 rows=2096 width=25) (actual time=360.555..455.798 rows=1579 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: ((stripe_balance_transactions.source)::text = (stripe_charges.stripe_id)::text)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stripe_balance_transactions  (cost=75.16..3924.19 rows=2016 width=30) (actual time=0.756..1.644 rows=1610 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((account_id = 93) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-01-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-02-19 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_balance_transactions_account_type_created  (cost=0.00..74.66 rows=2016 width=0) (actual time=0.732..0.732 rows=1610 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((account_id = 93) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-01-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-02-19 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Hash  (cost=18027.34..18027.34 rows=326080 width=31) (actual time=358.523..358.523 rows=216688 loops=1)
               Buckets: 2048  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 423kB
               ->  Seq Scan on stripe_charges  (cost=0.00..18027.34 rows=326080 width=31) (actual time=0.065..233.197 rows=216688 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((NOT refunded) AND (invoice IS NOT NULL))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 131346
 Total runtime: 457.260 ms
(15 rows)
```

I'm running Postgres 9.3.1.

EDIT: Here are current indexes...

```
# stripe_charges #
"stripe_charges_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_account_ref_created_plan" btree (account_id, refunded, created, plan)
"index_stripe_charges_on_account_id" btree (account_id)
"index_stripe_charges_on_account_id_and_amount" btree (account_id, amount)
"index_stripe_charges_on_account_id_and_amount_and_created" btree (account_id, amount, created)
"index_stripe_charges_on_account_id_and_paid_and_created" btree (account_id, paid, created)
"index_stripe_charges_on_account_id_and_stripe_id" btree (account_id, stripe_id)
"index_stripe_charges_on_customer" btree (customer)
"index_stripe_charges_on_invoice" btree (invoice)
"index_stripe_charges_on_is_projected" btree (is_projected)
"index_stripe_charges_on_is_projected_and_projected" btree (is_projected, projected)
"index_stripe_charges_on_parent_charge" btree (parent_charge)
"index_stripe_charges_on_plan" btree (plan)
"index_stripe_charges_on_projected" btree (projected)
"index_stripe_charges_on_refunded" btree (refunded)
"index_stripe_charges_on_stripe_id" btree (stripe_id)

# stripe_balance_transactions #
"stripe_balance_transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_balance_transactions_account_type_created" btree (account_id, type, created)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_account_id" btree (account_id)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_account_id_and_stripe_id" btree (account_id, stripe_id)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_plan" btree (plan)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_source" btree (source)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_stripe_id" btree (stripe_id)
"index_stripe_balance_transactions_on_type" btree (type)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on stripe_charges.stripe_ip? Try one on (s_b_t.account_id, s_b_t.type, s_b_t.created).

Comment: @bma: I do indeed have both of those indexes already.

Comment: what plan do you get if set you "set enable_seqscan = off" ?

Comment: Show all of your indexes.

Comment: @jjanes Turning seqscan off didn't do much. If anything it slowed things down slightly.

Comment: Wow, them's alotta indexes! You probably want to regularly visit pg_stat_user_indexes for those tables and see which indexes are not used. Out of curiousity, have you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` recently?

Comment: @Shpigford The reason to turning off enable_seqscan is force it into a different plan, to see what one it will use.  If it is not using index_stripe_charges_on_stripe_id, is that because it (correctly) believes it to be slower than the seq scan, or for some other reason?  Seeing the plan will help figure that out, even if it is slower

Comment: @bma: I have (and just did it now as well). No change in total runtime.

Comment: `ON stripe_balance_transactions.source = stripe_charges.stripe_id` what are the data types of `stripe_balance_transactions.source` and `stripe_charges.stripe_id` ? in short: PLEASE ADD THE TABLE DEFINITIONS TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Getting indexes correct is a try and test exercise and you are often working with a moving target.  With that in mind can you try adding a partial index on stripe_charges.refunded = false) AND (stripe_charges.invoice IS NOT NULL. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html it will look something like: CREATE INDEX stripe_charges_stripe_id_filtered ON stripe_charges (stripe_id)
WHERE refunded = false
  AND invoice IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Where does `fee` come from? For performance optimization you should *always* include (relevant parts of the) table definitions - what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Which of your `WHERE` conditions are stable? Which change? Can you define a superset of interesting rows that excludes a non-trivial portion of the tables? Cardinalities of your tables (how many rows)?

Answer (score 1):

After reformatting your query, the conditions on `created` should be re-written to:

```
SELECT b.created, fee, c.plan 
FROM   stripe_charges              c
JOIN   stripe_balance_transactions b ON b.source = c.stripe_id 
WHERE  c.refunded = FALSE
AND    c.invoice IS NOT NULL
AND    b.account_id = 93 
AND    b.type = 'charge'
AND   b.created >= '2013-01-20 00:00'
AND   b.created <  '2014-02-20 00:00'
ORDER  BY b.created;
```

For maximum performance, you would employ [partial, multicolumn covering indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html) along these lines:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON stripe_charges (stripe_id, fee, plan)
WHERE refunded = FALSE
AND   invoice IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX bar_idx ON stripe_balance_transactions (account_id, source, created)
WHERE  type = 'charge';
```

But this is a stab in the dark without knowing all th details. Consider this related answer on dba.SE from yesterday with more information and links for **covering indexes**:
[Very slow execution of a simple query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59170/very-slow-execution-of-a-simple-query/59231#59231)

As [@bma suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2521566/bma) in his comment: test whether all your indexes are actually used. You can check `pg_stat_user_indexes`, or if you should be using pgAdmin you click on the "Statistics" tab (top right) for an index or for the collection of indexes of a table.